# Get Mechanize to handle cookies from an arbitrary POST (to log into a website programmatically)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, screen-scraping, mechanize

I want to log into https://www.t-mobile.com/ programmatically. My first idea was to use Mechanize to submit the login form:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2010-04-08_1440.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2010-04-08_1440.png)

However, it turns out that this isn't even a real form. Instead, when you click "Log in" some javascript grabs the values of the fields, creates a new form dynamically, and submits it.

"Log in" button HTML:

```
<button onclick="handleLogin(); return false;" class="btnBlue" id="myTMobile-login"><span>Log in</span></button>
```

The `handleLogin()` function:

```
function handleLogin() {
    if (ValidateMsisdnPassword()) { // client-side form validation logic
        var a = document.createElement("FORM");
        a.name = "form1";
        a.method = "POST";
        a.action = mytmoUrl; // defined elsewhere as https://my.t-mobile.com/Login/LoginController.aspx
        var c = document.createElement("INPUT");
        c.type = "HIDDEN";
        c.value = document.getElementById("myTMobile-phone").value; // the value of the phone number input field
        c.name = "txtMSISDN";
        a.appendChild(c);
        var b = document.createElement("INPUT");
        b.type = "HIDDEN";
        b.value = document.getElementById("myTMobile-password").value; // the value of the password input field
        b.name = "txtPassword";
        a.appendChild(b);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.submit();
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I could simulate this form submission by POSTing the form data to `https://my.t-mobile.com/Login/LoginController.aspx` with `Net::HTTP#post_form`, but I don't know how to get the resultant cookie into Mechanize so I can continue to scrape the UI available when I'm logged in.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a direct **TOS Violation**.
"You agree not to: ...access, monitor or copy any content or information on the Site using any robot, spider, scraper or other automated means or any manual process;" 
https://www.t-mobile.com/Templates/Popup.aspx?WT.z_unav=ftr__useterms&PAsset=Ftr_Ftr_TermsOfUse&print=true

Comment: @rlb.usa: Hm... the TOS say you can't "access... any content ... using .. any manual process"... I'd say that's going to be hard to abide by unless you don't use the service in any way whatsoever. :)

Comment: @retracile: you are obviously obliged by their TOS to turn your brain off when accessing t-mobile's site.

Comment: @rlb-usa: So?  Are you the TOS police?  Breaking a "TOS" is not even illegal, for crying out loud.

Comment: I think what @rlb is trying to say is, any answers provided are aiding  @Horace in circumventing T-Mobile's TOS and existing security measures. And that most likely this will be considered abuse by T-Mobile resulting in possible account disconnection. Also, they're likely to revise the form submission process specifically to break scrapers like @Horace is trying to build...

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this to login and save the cookie so you won't have to do it again. Of course you will need to come up with your own logic to post it directly but this is how I use Mechanize's built in cookie_jar method to save cookies.

```
if !agent.cookie_jar.load('cookies.yml')
  page = agent.get('http://site.com')

  form = page.forms.last
  form.email = 'email'
  form.password = 'password'

  page = agent.submit(form)

  agent.cookie_jar.save_as('cookies.yml')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use the FireFox [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) extension to figure out what exactly is going on for these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid Net::HTTP; try with:

```
post(url, query={}, headers={})
```

directly from [Mechanize class](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize.html).